Comic story with a symbiotic brain alien saving an astronaut drifting in space
An ancient alien who was dormant in a micro capsule hits the helmet of a spaceman (probably after an accident) drifting hopelessly in space. The alien connects with his brain as the microscopic hole in the helmet is frozen shut. The alien explains that his species had always lived in the brains of ape-like creatures. The alien helps him save himself. They become a good team. The spaceman character has a blue and a brown eye. I cannot remember the name of the comic story! It might be Franco-Belgian or Italian. I read it in late 80's.
